# How to import data with markers - but excluding those markers?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, matrix, data-import

When I go to import a matrix of data, in the first row of the first column there is a marker for every new time data is acquired and this marker is interfering with how MATLAB imports the data.

Is there a way to code this out?

for example:

'>1 6 1 1 -0.00161

1 6 1 2 -0.00140

1 6 1 3 -0.00145

1 6 1 4 -0.00153

1 6 1 5 -0.00120

1 6 1 6 -0.00076

I would prefer to not manually remove the `>` from the data as there will be potentially thousands.

Comment: From what are you importing data? And to what format?

Comment: I am importing data from a txt file and trying to then sort the data and average among other things. But the ">" is the monkey wrench in the code right now

Answer (score 0):

If you're under *nix system or you have cygwin then you can get rid of these `>` if you send this output to the command `sed`. For instance:

```
user@host $ cat out.txt
>0 5 3 4  

0 6 4 3

>1 5 3 6

1 2 4 5
user@host $ cat out.txt |sed 's/>//g'
```

If you need to store this new output to a file:
    user@host $ cat out.txt

> 0 5 3 4

```
0 6 4 3

>1 5 3 6

1 2 4 5
user@host $ cat out.txt |sed 's/>//g' > out_without_unneeded_symbols.txt
user@host $ cat out_without_unneeded_symbols.txt
0 5 3 4  

0 6 4 3

1 5 3 6

1 2 4 5
```

If this output is taken from some program at current dir:

```
user@host $ ./some_program |sed 's/>//g'
```

Comment: I am having trouble duplicating your results, but I have a feeling that is my issue. I did find using the manual import option that the data will be imported w/o the ">", is there a simple way to program that into matlab during the import, or will that only be possible while manually importing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation in MATLAB:

```
% read file lines as a cell array of strings
fid = fopen('file.dat', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','');
C = C{1};
fclose(fid);

% find marker locations
markers = strncmp('>', C, 1);

% remove markers
C = regexprep(C, '^>', '');

% parse numbers into a numeric matrix
X = regexp(C, '\s+', 'split');
X = str2double(vertcat(X{:}));
```

The result:

```
% the full matrix
>> X
X =
     0     5     3     4
     0     6     4     3
     1     5     3     6
     1     2     4     5

% only the marked rows
>> X(markers,:)
ans =
     0     5     3     4
     1     5     3     6
```

Comment: if the numbers in the matrix are
1 0.05 4 5
1 66 1.5 4

etc vertcat will give me an error do to the dimensions. Is there a quick fix for this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post an example of this data in the question (correctly formatted).. The data shown previously works fine.

Comment: I fixed the question with a better example. My apologizes. I forget how touchy matlab gets

Comment: Is the single quote at the beginning part of the file? Please check the formatting again, and indent the text by 4 space to get it properly rendered... It's difficult to answer these kinds of questions unless you show an actual part of the data, not some made up example!

Comment: no the single quote is not part of the file. I can not get the > to show up with out it. Once again, my apologizes.

Comment: you might wanna read this help page to learn how to properly format posts correctly. The site uses Markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting